# populate checkbox list with xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm trying to populate a checkbox list with an xml file.  I thought it would be similar to populating a dropdown list with xml but I'm stuck on it.  Here's the xml I'm loading:

```
<Families>
<IdCode>0000</IdCode>
<FamilyName id="0000">Doe</FamilyName>
<ChildName id="0000">Ben</ChildName>
<MomName>Doe, Jane</MomName>
<DadName>Doe, John</DadName>
</Families>
```

And here's the code I'm using:

```
var query = xdoc2.Descendants("Families")
                .Elements("ChildName")
                .Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("id").Value == inputPassword)
                .Select(c => (string)c)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "value";
            CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "text";
            CheckBoxList1.DataSource = query;
            CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

The error I'm getting when I run the application is this: "DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'text'." When I remove the .DataTextField line it gives the same error for "value".  I have a feeling it's something simple but I can't figure it out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add the closing tag for Families?

```
<Families>
<IdCode>0000</IdCode>
<FamilyName id="0000">Doe</FamilyName>
<ChildName id="0000">Ben</ChildName>
<MomName>Doe, Jane</MomName>
<DadName>Doe, John</DadName>
</Families>
```

And actually wouldn't it be better to structure it something more like:

```
<Families>
     <Family>
          <IdCode>0000</IdCode>
          <FamilyName id="0000">Doe</FamilyName>
          <ChildName id="0000">Ben</ChildName>
          <MomName>Doe, Jane</MomName>
          <DadName>Doe, John</DadName>
     </Family>
</Families>
```

Comment: I just forgot to copy the closing tag for Families.  I export the file from Access then add the id attributes, I was trying to avoid changing the structure too much.